# Interrupting syscalls in threads on linux

Tags: linux, pthreads, signals, interrupt, system-calls

I have a pthread that runs in a loop, calling `accept()` in a blocking manner. Is there any way to interrupt that call from another thread? Everything points to sending the thread a signal, but apparently you can only send a *process* a signal.

I can't just kill the thread because then it leaves the socket open. And that's not very clean anyway. Is there really no way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can signal a thread using [`pthread_kill(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html).

> The `pthread_kill()` function sends the signal sig to thread, another
>   thread in the same process as the caller.
>
> If a signal handler is installed, the handler will be invoked in the
>   thread *thread*.

Note, **you don't have to kill the thread**; you can send a signal that simply makes `accept` fail with `EINTR`.

Answer (score -1):

Either use `select()`, or send the singal to the process (this will be a problem if you just want to interupt one of the threads).