# interruption of blocked I/O functions

Tags: c, unix, io

I have a thread, that reads serial device (*/dev/ttyUSB0*), and writes data to stdout :

```
void io_thread_func () {

    int serial_port = open(settings.port, O_RDWR);

    while (1) {

        char buf[100];

        int n = read(serial_port, buf, 100);

        fwrite(buf, 1, n, stdout);

    }

}
```

How I can interrupt "*read(...)*" *syscall* from another thread ?
Can I call "*close(serial_port)*" from another thread to interrupt all I/O blocking functions ?
(I need to interrupt I/O blocking functions to close the thread correctly)

Comment: Gleb: I'd hazard that your question is practically identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882379/how-to-interrupt-a-fread-call - would you agree?

Comment: @TonyDelroy It's not clear how useful any of the answers there are.

Comment: Similar question, check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910335/interrupting-syscalls-in-threads-on-linux

Comment: `int  pthread_kill(pthread_t tid, int sig);` sends a signal `sig` to another thread, within the same process

Comment: @Barmar: if that's the case, Gleb should cite the other question and say how the answers there were tried and failed for his purpose (or offer a bounty for better solutions to the existing question, but Gleb can't do that as a new contributor - none of them internet point thingies).

Comment: is there a syscall "interrupt_all_io_functions(int fd)" ? or not ?

Comment: posix(?) signals - is only way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How i can interrupt "read(...)" syscall from another thread ? Can i call "close(serial_port)" from another thread to interrupt all I/O blocking functions ? (i need to interrupt I/O blocking functions to close the thread correctly)

You can send a signal to the thread. That will interrupt the `read` function.

You absolutely cannot close the serial port from another thread. That can cause all kinds of disasters. Consider:

1. This thread is about to call `read` but hasn't called it yet.
2. Another thread calls `close` on the `serial_port`.
3. Before the first thread can call `read` another thread `accepts` an incoming socket connection for a critical internal system purpose.
4. That thread happens to get the same descriptor as `serial_port`.
5. This thread calls `read` then `fwrite`, dumping the data received on the critical socket to `stdout`.

Good thing it's `stdout`. Because a bug once caused that exact same scenario -- except sensitive data was sent to random inbound connections from the Internet rather than `stdout`.

Comment: is there a syscall "interrupt_all_io_functions(int fd)" ? or not ?

Comment: posix(?) signals - is only way to solve this problem ?

Comment: @glebzheglov Signals is one way. There are lots of other ways. Ideally, you just wouldn't block in a function you didn't want to wait forever in. For example, you can `poll` both the serial port and a local socket. To unblock the call to `poll`, you can just send a dummy byte on the local socket. There are lots of ways to do this.